# T-SQL help needed to create a result set in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to display data in the following format:

[image]

Suppose I select 08-2013 date to display data. Actually this is a consumer data.So **This month** column should calculate data ( i.e. Count OR SUM ) for Aug-2013 and **From April** column should calculate data ( i.e. Count OR SUM ) from **Apr-2013 to Aug-2013**.

So now my problem is that how can i write T-SQL to get this result set.
I can calculate **This month** data and **From April** data separately but how to merge these two result in single result set.

Do I have to create a table to get this result set.

**PS**

OK so I take an example of first row **1) Sample text 1** just to represent individual calculation for **This month** and **From April**

```
DECLARE @BILL_DATE DATETIME
SET @BILL_DATE= '2013-08-15'
--Seprate result set for THIS MONTH and ROW For Sample text 1
SELECT 
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='1' THEN C.CONSUMER_NO END),0) AS CAT_1_THIS_MONTH,
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='2' THEN C.CONSUMER_NO END),0) AS CAT_2_THIS_MONTH,
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='3' THEN C.CONSUMER_NO END),0) AS CAT_3_THIS_MONTH
FROM CONSUMER C
INNER JOIN BILLING B ON C.CONSUMER_NO = B.CONSUMER_NO
WHERE B.BILL_DATE = @BILL_DATE AND (more condition will be as per For Sample text 1)
--Seprate result set for FROM APRIL and ROW For Sample text 1
SELECT 
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='1' THEN C.UNIT END),0) AS CAT_1_FROM_APRIL,
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='2' THEN C.UNIT END),0) AS CAT_2_FROM_APRIL,
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='3' THEN C.UNIT END),0) AS CAT_3_FROM_APRIL
FROM CONSUMER C
INNER JOIN BILLING B ON C.CONSUMER_NO = B.CONSUMER_NO
WHERE B.BILL_DATE BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND @BILL_DATE  AND (more condition will be as per For Sample text 1)
```

Now my aim is to display these two individual result in one row in two column ( i.e. This month and From April )

Comment: There is no circumstance where you have to create a table to get a result set from an existing database. You can of course create a temp table to simply your thought process, but it is not needed. To help you though, we woudl need to know more about your database structure and how you are calculating.

Comment: What does "Count OR Sum" means?

Comment: You could show us your two queries that return **This Month** and **From April** separately, and we might be able to help you put them together.

Comment: Hello friends I have made changes in Question.Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a condition that will include the entire period in the WHERE clause
Thus, you can use nested case expression to check the month August

```
DECLARE @BILL_DATE datetime,
        @sDate datetime, 
        @eDate datetime
SET @BILL_DATE = '20130815'        
SET @sDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @BILL_DATE), 0)
SET @eDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @sDate)

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN B.BILL_DATE >= @sDate AND B.BILL_DATE < @eDate 
                  THEN CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='1' 
                            THEN C.CONSUMER_NO END END) AS CAT_1_THIS_MONTH,       
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='1' THEN C.UNIT END) AS CAT_1_FROM_APRIL,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN B.BILL_DATE >= @sDate AND B.BILL_DATE < @eDate 
                  THEN CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='2' 
                            THEN C.CONSUMER_NO END END) AS CAT_2_THIS_MONTH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='2' THEN C.UNIT END) AS CAT_2_FROM_APRIL,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN B.BILL_DATE >= @sDate AND B.BILL_DATE < @eDate 
                  THEN CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='3' 
                            THEN C.CONSUMER_NO END END) AS CAT_3_THIS_MONTH,              
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAT_CODE='3' THEN C.UNIT END) AS CAT_3_FROM_APRIL
FROM CONSUMER C INNER JOIN BILLING B ON C.CONSUMER_NO = B.CONSUMER_NO
WHERE B.BILL_DATE >= '20130401 00:00:00' AND B.BILL_DATE < @eDate
  AND (more condition will be as per For Sample text 1)
```